# How to add shared library search path to a executable file?

Tags: shared-libraries, ld, ldd

I build the ffmpeg with librtmp. My librtmp is at /opt/librtmp/lib. When I execute the ffmpeg, it said:

```
./ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: librtmp.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I use ldd command it displays **not found**:

```
[qty@testing bin]# ldd ffmpeg 
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff15576000)
        librtmp.so.0 => not found
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00002b9a71e10000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b9a72025000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b9a722a8000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b9a724c3000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b9a71bf2000)
```

I know my so at:

```
[qty@testing bin]# ls -alh  /opt/librtmp/lib/
total 300K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Sep 25 17:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4.0K Sep 25 17:10 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 158K Sep 25 17:10 librtmp.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   12 Sep 25 17:10 librtmp.so -> librtmp.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 118K Sep 25 17:10 librtmp.so.0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 25 17:10 pkgconfig
```

I found several ways to fix the problem

- modify /etc/ld.so.conf, but it required a supper user
- set LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, but it is not conventient to users
- pass rpath to gcc, like this

**configure args for my ffmpeg**

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/librtmp/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --disable-doc \
--disable-ffserver --disable-avdevice \
--disable-postproc --disable-avfilter --disable-bsfs \
--disable-filters \
--disable-asm \
--disable-bzlib \
--enable-librtmp \
--prefix=/opt/ffmpeg \
--extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath,/opt/librtmp/lib"
```

Assume there are no source code to re-compile? How do add the shared library search path to a executable file ?

Comment: I did a symlink of /usr/lib/i486-linux-gnu/librtmp.so into /usr/local/lib and ffmpeg runs like a charm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [addrpath](http://quatramaran.ens.fr/~godfroy/clipper/addrpathen.html) to add an RPATH to your elf file.

The RPATH will work like LD_LIBRARY_PATH, that is, telling the dynamic loader to search for the shared libraries in that path. RPATH will be permanently in your ELF file.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *quatramaran.ens.fr’s server IP address could not be found*.

Answer (score 8):

I realize that OP has probably moved on but this is the kind of thing that NixOS does regularly and they have released a tool for this very problem. Also this was a problem I had before even hearing of NixOS.

Here's an example usage of their tool `patchelf`

...
Likewise, you can change the RPATH, the linker search path embedded into executables and dynamic libraries:

```
patchelf --set-rpath /opt/my-libs/lib:/foo/lib program
```

This causes the dynamic linker to search in `/opt/my-libs/lib` and `/foo/lib` for the shared libraries needed by program....

From https://nixos.org/patchelf.html

Answer (score 3):

## nixos

this **might be nixos specific** but provides an interesting insight on ldd/patchelf:

https://lastlog.de/blog/posts/playing_FTL_on_NIXOS.html

## ubuntu

on ubuntu/fedora you would use: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with a starter script `./ftl`, again, see my above posting about FTL and how it is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

My fix to this problem is to install librtmp into /usr/local/lib and run 'sudo ldconfig' after installing it.
Ffmpeg can then be configured simply by adding --enable-librtmp.
For me this works fine: No system modifications necessary!