# Distribute Shared Object with Executable (Best Practice?)

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries, ld

I need to distribute a version of OpenSSL with my application. I can't use Ubuntu's because the distro currently disables TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2.

I've read a few posts about how to solve a missing shared object (for example, [How to add shared library search path to a executable file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580184/how-to-add-shared-library-search-path-to-a-executable-file)).

My concern is that I have a library that has the same name as that of the disto, and its binary compatible with the distro.

My question is, is there a best practice for distributing a shared objects where collision are expected?

Answer (score 2):

Put the SO in a private directory, and add that directory to the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in a wrapper script before running the executable.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. There's two problems with that (sorry, I should have listed them). First, I don't want people to have to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Second, this runs as root, so LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not honored (even with `sudo -E`).

Comment: @noloader people don't need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, you create a shell script, place it together with your executable, the shell script sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH and runs the executable. People run the shell script (with e.g. sudo) instead of the real executable.

Comment: Thanks nos. Is there any reading on Best Practices for doing this? I know there's a lot of potential problems with the runtime linker (DLL Hell and Binary Planting are not just Windows problems). See, for example, [Breaking the links: Exploiting the linker](https://www.nth-dimension.org.uk/pub/BTL.pdf‎).

Answer (score 2):

As opposed to setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable in a wrapper script, you can also compile your executable with extra linker flags that add directories to search for shared libraries.

The linker flag is `-Wl,-rpath,<path to lib directory>`

As an example, say you are installing your app to `/opt/myapp/bin`, you could also have a folder `/opt/myapp/lib`, and in that folder you place your `libssl.so`. Then you would compile your app with the extra linker flag `-Wl,-rpath,/opt/myapp/lib`. Then when you run your app, it will look in that folder first before searching the standard folders for shared libraries.